# Spring Boot trouble by deployment on Tomcat Server 8.5

Tags: java, spring, path, pom.xml, tomcat8.5

i have troubles by deployment my Spring Boot Project on Tomcat Server 8.5.
This project work fine in Eclipse on local Tomcat but after deployment on global Tomcat Server i see error 404
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA8mS.png)

if i write the source path like absolut path-> `<body background="./images/brickwall.png">`
than is all ok.
this is my pom-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>cth</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaaaa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>bbbb</name>
    <description> Spring Boot Projekt</description>     
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have set the property `server.servlet.contextPath`, as this is for embedded Tomcat only. It is not needed if you are deploying the application to another Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for answer Kashan, but i haven't set this property.

Comment: My best guess is that the issue is related to the Tomcat configuration